# Installing Bootstrap via Grunt. How do I run npm install

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, npm

In the Bootstrap documentation after Node.js and Grunt have been installed they say I have to :

> Navigate to the root /bootstrap/ directory, then run npm install

What's that mean? I've open a folder with Bootstrap source files but how am I supposed to "run npm install'? I am totally confused.

Comment: It's referring to the command line. What platform are you running on? The answer will depend on whether you're running on Windows/Linux/OSX

Comment: I had to run a command line from the source Bootstrap folder and type "npm install". Now I got it. Shift + right click did the trick on my Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so, [download and install Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).  The process varies per platform, so refer to the download link.

Once you've installed Node.js, you **may** need to open a new shell or even reboot for the any new environment variables to take affect.

Once you have Node.js installed, you should be able to:

```
cd ./bootstrap
npm install
```